# How does TFSA contribution room carryover work, e.g. unused amounts and withdrawals?

Tags: canada, contribution, tfsa, limits

Is the TFSA contribution limit per year $5000/person?

How are unused contributions carried over?

If last year I contributed only $3000, then this year, would I have $7000 contribution room available?

Also, if this year I withdraw $5000, does that affect my TFSA contribution room?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the TFSA contribution limit per year $5000/person?

The annual TFSA dollar limit for  2009, 2010, 2011 and 2012 was $5,000. For the years 2013, 2014 and 2015 it was $5,500.

> How are unused contributions carried over?

Any unused TFSA contribution room from the previous year and any withdrawals made from the TFSA in the previous year are carried over.

> If last year I contributed only $3000, then this year, would I have $7000 contribution room available?

You would have $2500 left over from last year and an extra $5500 this year which equals to $8000 assuming you maxed your TFSA in years previous and including 2013.

> Also, if this year I withdraw $5000, does that affect my TFSA contribution room?

You will get back the contribution room next year. Next year you will be able to contribute $5500 (2016) + $5000 (withdrawn this year) + $x (remaining contribution room).

You can go [here](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/tfsa-celi/wthdrwls-eng.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. If I withdraw 5000 this year, that does not affect my room for this year, correct?

Comment: @Victor123 it will not affect contribution room this year. You'll get the 5k contribution room back next year.